# Django how to retrieve values from a database for an existing post so that we can edit

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am displaying a form for a posting which has already been saved to the database. I am giving the user the option to view the values as they are in the database and give him the option to edit them. However, it is not working for dropdown. I have tried writing something but it does not display the correct values.

please help :(((

Here is the code snippet:

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="industry_type">Industry Type</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="industry_type" name="industry_type" selected=" 
                {{ internship.industry_type }}">
                    {% for ind_type in industry_types %}
                         <option value="{{ ind_type }}" {% if '{{ ind_type }}' == '{{ 
                         internship.industry_type }}' %}selected="selected" {% endif %}> 
                         {{ind_type}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>            
       </div>
```

views.py

```
def edit_internship(request, pid):
  internship = Internship.objects.get(id=pid)
  skills = InternshipSkill.objects.filter(internship=internship)
  emp_steps = InternshipEmpStep.objects.filter(internship=internship)
 .order_by('emp_step_no')

  industry_types = IndustryType.objects.all()
  context = {
        'industry_types': industry_types, 
        'internship': internship,
        'skills': skills,
        'emp_steps': emp_steps,
    } 
  return render(request, 'edit_internship.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi :) Can you edit your question to put up the code for your view (in views.py) please? It's hard to tell what information you are passing through to the template. Which bit isn't displaying?

Comment: @TomHamiltonStubber Hello :) Posted it. Industry types for the internship can be Information Tech, Banking, etc. I want to display the industry type that has been selected out of all the types in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is just because don't need to re-add the curly brackets in django's templates if you already have them:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="industry_type">Industry Type</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="industry_type" name="industry_type" selected="{{ internship.industry_type.pk }}">
    {% for ind_type in industry_types %}
       <option value="{{ ind_type.pk }}" {% if ind_type.pk == internship.industry_type.pk %}selected="selected" {% endif %}> 
         {{ ind_type }}
       </option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Also, don't forget the `.pk` argument to `ind_type` when declaring the value.

---

For future reference, I really recommend you use Django's forms when creating these, it makes your like SO much easier:

views.py

```py
class EditInternship(UpdateView):
    model = Internship
    template_name = 'edit_internship.html'
    form_class = EditInternshipForm

    def get_context_data(**kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx.update(
            skills=InternshipSkill.objects.filter(internship=internship),
            emp_steps=InternshipEmpStep.objects.filter(internship=internship).order_by('emp_step_no')
        )
        # You'll also have `form` already in the context
        return ctx


edit_internship = EditInternship.as_view()
```

forms.py

```py
class EditInternshipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Internship
        fields = 'industry_type', 'other_fields_on_the_model_you_want_to_edit'
```

edit_internship.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.industry_type }}
  {{ form.other_fields_you_want_to_edit }}
   <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit_button">
</form>
```

Comment: Do the options have any values rendered? Or are no options rendered?

Comment: @TonyHamiltonStubber, yeah but it shows the same option for all the internships even if they have different industry types

Comment: As it, the options in the dropdown are the same for every internship? Or the `selected` option is the same for each internship? I've just seen I should have typed `{% if ind_type.pk == internship.industry_type.pk %}`, and `selected="{{ internship.industry_type.pk }}"`, I'll change my answer

Comment: The selected option is the same for all. Btw, I have not made a foreign key relationship from internship.industry_type to industry type :/ This solution ain't working either

Comment: Oh if it's not a ForeignKey relation, what's the field internship.industry_type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231737/discussion-between-alpha-and-tom-hamilton-stubber).